# One of my final round interviewers only started at the company a month ago- red flag?

Tags: interviewing

Seemed fine to me but just want to gut check. I’m being considered for two different influencer marketing roles, one of which the folks interviewing me would report to me.

I assume the interview is to test my relative knowledge and see if we would work well together, but I learned that one of the interviewers only started in August. I’m wondering if that’s normal or if should be of concern.

After this I would interview with CMO.

Comment: Its not much of a concern. People change jobs all the time and people sometimes become busy. It can be pretty normal for someone important to join the interview as a replacement despite not having worked there for very long. They are still an employee of the company at the end of the day.

Comment: If a candidate has a concern on how long the interviewer had worked for that company, I would consider it red flag on the candidate.

Answer (score 6):

Not really.

We've had some new faces make huge massive changes and start throwing their weight around from day one.  When I did a little investigation found the guy was essentially a genius from the top college in the world and had written books on the topic.  And once I realized who he was and saw the impact of the changes he brought in my respect for him quadrupled overnight.

He could be a specialist the company brought in with a lot of experience and/or theoretical knowledge.

New in the company doesn't mean he doesn't know what he is doing.  In fact in a reputable company with careful interviewing processes it means you really need to make sure this guy is on board with hiring you.

Comment: That makes sense and appreciate the perspective. I’ve enjoyed chatting with everyone so far, so will stay the course.